# High and low line on candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I show high and low line on charts basically on candlestick chart.
Can you please provide any sample or reference for this.

Comment: For anyone's reference, this is what a candlestick chart is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart

Comment: That depends on the chart library you use and is probably mentioned in the documentation. Please provide an example of your code and reference to the library you use. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am using highchart library.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support candlestick series, you need to use Highstock, like in [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick).

Comment: yes, this support in highstock. Is there a way to get the min and max value for this to display the high and low lines. I am getting the values from the csv file which is ohlc.push([
    data[i][0], // the date
    data[i][1], // open
    data[i][2], // high
    data[i][3], // low
    data[i][4] // close
   ]); trhe min amd max for     data[i][4] // close.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017 there was no such a component in Highcharts. Now, using [the Highstock component](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/) the format for a candlestick is:

```
ohlc.push([
  data[i][0], // date
  data[i][1], // open
  data[i][2], // high <---
  data[i][3], // low <---
  data[i][4], // close
]);
```

I think your data may be missing a few rows. Here is [a sample CodePen](https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/GRoGaPO?editors=1010) with candlesticks, volume and zoom.

[image]

Comment: The horizontal line is not commng on high and low but the graph is coming

Comment: What you mean exactly @vishal? As far as I know there are no horizontal lines in candlestick charts.

Comment: Please check whether you get the horizontal and line for both open and close prices of candle

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly with "horizontal lines". What horizontal lines? You may be looking for this type of candles: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/oNbPzda?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

put the crosshair label enabled so that atleast you will see the horizontal line for one of the high or close price

Put this in chart at the level of series

```
yAxis: {
  crosshair: {
    label: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```